# Can I run the same PowerShell command on Exchange 2003 and Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange-2003, powershell

Can I run the same PowerShell scripts/commands on Exchange 2003 that I run for Exchange 2007? There are many articles on the web for using Exchange 2003 and PowerShell but I can't work out if the commands are different, the same or executed in a different way. Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the Exchange 2007 commandlets do not work with Exchange 2003 for the most part. It can be done, but the articles I'm seeing are leveraging .NET interfaces inside PowerShell in order to affect the Exch2003 environment, and that's not the same thing as "get-mailboxstatistics -server $Mailserver" at all.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2003 management via PowerShell is done using WMI and/or AD cmdlets such as Quest's AD cmdlets.  This is completely different and independent from the native cmdlets that come with Exchange 2007, which only work on Exchange 2007.  For more information I recommend reading up on Exchange 2003 WMI classes and the Get-WMIObject cmdlet in PowerShell, and using Quest's AD cmdlets for any AD modifications you want to make.